# SQL Argument of LIMIT must not contain variables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the tables `A(ida PK,entry_year, . . .)`, `B(idc PK,ida FK,value1, . . .)` and `C(year PK,value2, . . .)`
I'm trying to select the first n value1 from table B (associated with a specific ida of table A), where n is the value2 of table C with the same C.year as A.entry_year. The code is similar to this one:

```
select value1 from A as Alpha join B using(ida)
where A.ida=$1
limit (select value2 from C where year=(select entry_year from A where A.ida=Alpha.ida))
```

But i get the following error: Argument of LIMIT must not contain variables.
What am I supposed to do?

thanks!

Comment: you have Alpha alias in limit - you cant join in limit... what did you mean for `(select value2 from C where year=(select entry_year from A where A.ida=Alpha.ida))`?.. verbally

Comment: @VaoTsun Ok i will phrase my example with easier names.Table A is a student.Table C is GraduationRules of the school.The latter one has the rules for each year on entry. For example, students that came in the school in the year 2017 will have to pass 35 courses in total, while students in 2018 will have to pass 34 etc.Table B contains applies from students(table A).I want the first n applies from table B, where n is the number of applies GraduationRules (table C) permits each student(table A)..so in the limit clause i need to find this specific restriction that is different for every student!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [row_number](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) to simulate LIMIT.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select 
        value1,
        entry_year,
        row_number() OVER() AS rownum --Probably you should use PARTITION BY here using student id if you want to retrieve more than one student
    from 
        A as Alpha 
        join B using(ida)
    where A.ida=$1) as tmp
JOIN C ON (C.year = tmp.entry_year)
WHERE rownum <= C.value2
```

Comment: @milezzi ok i see, thanks...but what's the point of limit clause then? i'm kind of confused now.

Comment: @LaprimoSiesta LIMIT allow you to retrieve only specified number of rows from a query, eg: `SELECT * FROM table_1 LIMIT 100;` --will get only 100 rows of table_1,that isn't what you want, more info [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-limit.html)